# Is this question well posed?

Tags: paradox

Suppose that there are many people in a room, and that all of the people in this room have to attend a logic class in 1 hour. Suppose that each person is either doing homework that has to be turned in before the logic class begins, or has no homework to do. A particularly bright student in the room has just enough time to finish the homework of all people in the room who don't have enough time to finish the homework themselves. 
Question: does this student have logic homework to do?

Comment: It's like the barber of the regiment, who shaves everyone who doesn't shave themselves -- so who shaves the barber? It's a way of posing [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_paradox)

Comment: This question brings in, near the end, the concept that some people don't have time to finish their homework. The One Bright Student can eliminate that. But the question is only the last sentence, and has nothing to do with the rest. @JosephWeissman: I thought so, but it doesn't actually all link up. Him having homework is unrelated to every preceding sentence.

Comment: The OBS's ability only applies to those who can't finish in time. If he has homework and is unable to complete it, there is a paradox. If he has homework and is able to complete it, or if he does not have homework, there is no paradox. So there is a paradox involved, but unlike Russell's, it may not even need to be considered. Then too, it is not stated that there are, in fact, any students who don't have time. There are simply too many exits. It could be refined to be Russell's paradox applied to students, but it isn't currently.

Comment: Unless we're told what the question is intended to teach, I'm not sure what we can do. It *is* a question. If it's to see if students can remove the extra parts of the question, the correct answer is "Yes, this is a well posed question." if it is to introduce the concept of a paradox through a localized version of Russell's paradox, then the answer is "No, but here's how you could fix that:". Until we know that, we can't answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question, "does this student have logic homework to do?" means that the student has *his own* logic homework to do, then yes, the question is well-posed, in the sense that it does have an answer: the student cannot have his *own* logic homework, if he has "just enough time to finish the homework of all people ['all' here must include himself] in the room who don't have enough time to finish the homework themselves."

For, assuming that the student has his own homework to do leads to Russell's paradox:

He has just enough time to finish the homework of all people who don't have enough time to finish their own homework. So if he finishes his own homework, then he doesn't have enough time to finish his homework; if he doesn't finish his homework, then he does have enough time to finish his homework.

Hence, answering "yes" to the (yes/no) question, "does the student have [his own] logic homework to do" leads to a paradox. Answering "no" clearly poses no problems.

Note:

If nobody has homework to do, then "no" is obviously the answer.

If everybody has homework to do, then in particular so does the bright student, which leads to Russell's paradox, and hence the conclusion that at least the student cannot have his own hw to do.

If at least one person has hw, and all people who do have hw are able to do it on time, then again the bright student cannot have any homework, for if he did, he would have just enough time to finish nobody's homework, and hence, not even his own, which again leads to a paradox.

Comment: This argument looks correct to me.  Any attempt to say that Mr Smarty-Pants has homework to do leads to a Russell-style paradox.

Comment: The main problem, though, is the fact that you can say no. You may have a paradox, but you may not. Russell's paradox traps you in the paradox, because either value leads to the same problem. If this problem is designed to make students consider the concept of a paradox, it also implies that you can ignore them. It is the same as "If this coin lands on heads, there is a paradox. If it lands on tails, there is no paradox. Which side does it land on?" There is no single conclusion.

Comment: @Magus I am struggling to see how a no answer may lead to a paradox. Is it the use of the word "the" rather than "their" in the phrase "to do **the** homework themselves".  That this leaves open the possibility that he cannot complete the task.

Comment: @NickR: You misunderstand me. I'm specifically saying that the question as posed currently cannot be reduced to Russell's paradox, because Russell's paradox is a paradox no matter which answer you try to substitute, whereas this is **not** the case here, as you say. Since this question appears to be an attempt to relate Russell's paradox to students in order to teach them more effectively, I simply say that it misses, which is a problem. If the goal is to get them to think about the paradox, it may be enough. But the final question *may* not lead to a paradox, potentially weakening it.

Comment: @Magus Oh, I see.  Yes, that is clear and an important point.  It does seem to miss the mark in this regard.  Thanks.

Comment: @Magus: I don't see how the well-posedness of the question ("does the bright student have his own logic homework to do?") is dependent upon who answers it. The question is a "yes" or "no" question, and it is clear that the situation does not permit both answers: the student cannot both have homework to do, and not have homework to do.  Thus, asking whether this yes/no question is well-posed seems to be equivalent to asking whether whether, under the hypotheses of the problem, the yes/no question can be answered: does the situation presented contain enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @Magus: What do you interpret "is the question well-posed" to mean? As an example, consider this problem: (1) it is 7 in the evening where John lives, Q: Is John hungry? Obviously we cannot answer the Q with the information given, nothing that is said about John can lead us to logically conclude that John is or isn't hungry. If, additionally, we know: (2) John is always hungry after 12 hours of fasting; (3) John ate last 13h ago; (4) John is never hungry at 7 pm. Then the problem is again ill-posed, because (2)+(3) => J. is hungry, but (4) => John isn't hungry. We get a contradiction.

Comment: @user9151: But we don't have enough information to answer the question, unless you think the answer is 'A would create a paradox, so it must be B'. But I expect the goal of the question is to teach students about philosophy. I've stated the problem with that clearly enough.